# How to split strings into text and number?

Tags: python, string, split

I'd like to split strings like these

```
'foofo21'
'bar432'
'foobar12345'
```

into

```
['foofo', '21']
['bar', '432']
['foobar', '12345']
```

Does somebody know an easy and simple way to do this in python?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I would approach this by using `re.match` in the  following way:

```
import re
match = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)", 'foofo21', re.I)
if match:
    items = match.groups()
print(items)
>> ("foofo", "21")
```

Comment: you probably want \w instead of [a-z] and \d instead of [0-9]

Comment: @Dan:
Using \w is a poor choice as it matches all alphanumeric characters, not just a-z. So, the entire string would be caught in the first group.

Comment: Not if you match it ungreedy as I do in my answer.

Comment: @Bernard, notice the  `re.I` at the end. That makes case a non-issue.

Comment: You might get some false positives using this method. If you tried m = r.match("abc123def"), then m.groups() would get you ('abc', '123'). That's because re.match() matches from the beginning of a string but doesn't need to match the entire string.

Comment: If that's a concern, you can tack '\b' (IIRC) at the end, to specify that the match must end at a word boundary (or '$' to match the end of the string).

Comment: How can this be extended to str-digit-str-digit such as p6max20 to get p=6, max=20? "( )( )( )( )" four grouping?

Comment: `re.split('(\d+)', t)`

Comment: <> 
match = re.split(r'(\d+)', text)
if match.isdigit():
     #you get the number
     int(match)
else:
    #you get the text 
     match
<>

Answer (score 64):

```py
def mysplit(s):
    head = s.rstrip('0123456789')
    tail = s[len(head):]
    return head, tail
```

```
>>> [mysplit(s) for s in ['foofo21', 'bar432', 'foobar12345']]
[('foofo', '21'), ('bar', '432'), ('foobar', '12345')]
```

Comment: Comparing timing for this answer to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430102/3585557), on my machine, using a single example (case study, not representative of all uses), this `str().rstrip()` method was roughly 4x faster.  Also, it does not require another import.

Comment: It is more pythonic.

Comment: don't know how relevant this is but, when I try FOO_BAR10.34 it gave me 'FOO_BAR10.' and '34' and then when I re-apply mysplits to the first element, it gives me the same thing. I know my issue is slightly different.

Comment: But I can slice 'FOO_BAR10.' to remove the '.', then re-apply the function to get what I want. +1.

Comment: To split 'float' at the end add '.' to digits in rstrip() call.

Comment: there is `string.digits`

Comment: Nice, no imports needed. Only that this solution assumes the given text is of the format string+numeric. In the case of numeric+string, one would need to resort to lstrip(). But the OP's question already assumes the first case.

Answer (score 34):

Yet Another Option:

```
>>> [re.split(r'(\d+)', s) for s in ('foofo21', 'bar432', 'foobar12345')]
[['foofo', '21', ''], ['bar', '432', ''], ['foobar', '12345', '']]
```

Comment: Neat. Or even: [re.split(r'(\d+)', s)[0:2] for s in ...] getting rid of that extra empty string. Note though that compared with \w this is equivalent to [^|\d].

Comment: @PEZ: There may be more than one pair and an empty string may be at the begining of the list. You could remove empty strings with `[filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+)', s)) for s in ('foofo21','a1')]`

Answer (score 29):

```
>>> r = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
>>> m = r.match("foobar12345")
>>> m.group(1)
'foobar'
>>> m.group(2)
'12345'
```

So, if you have a list of strings with that format:

```
import re
r = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
strings = ['foofo21', 'bar432', 'foobar12345']
print [r.match(string).groups() for string in strings]
```

Output:

```
[('foofo', '21'), ('bar', '432'), ('foobar', '12345')]
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm always the one to bring up findall() =)

```
>>> strings = ['foofo21', 'bar432', 'foobar12345']
>>> [re.findall(r'(\w+?)(\d+)', s)[0] for s in strings]
[('foofo', '21'), ('bar', '432'), ('foobar', '12345')]
```

Note that I'm using a simpler (less to type) regex than most of the previous answers.

Comment: r'\w' matches '_'. I don't see '_' in the question.

Comment: I don't see A-Z in the question. It says "text and numbers".

Comment: @PEZ: If you allow any text except numbers then your regexp should be r'(\D+)(\d+)'.

Answer (score 11):

here is a simple function to seperate multiple words and numbers from a string of any length, the re method only seperates first two words and numbers. I think this will help everyone else in the future,

```
def seperate_string_number(string):
    previous_character = string[0]
    groups = []
    newword = string[0]
    for x, i in enumerate(string[1:]):
        if i.isalpha() and previous_character.isalpha():
            newword += i
        elif i.isnumeric() and previous_character.isnumeric():
            newword += i
        else:
            groups.append(newword)
            newword = i

        previous_character = i

        if x == len(string) - 2:
            groups.append(newword)
            newword = ''
    return groups

print(seperate_string_number('10in20ft10400bg'))
# outputs : ['10', 'in', '20', 'ft', '10400', 'bg']
```

Answer (score 4):

without using regex, using isdigit() built-in function, only works if starting part is text and latter part is number

```
def text_num_split(item):
    for index, letter in enumerate(item, 0):
        if letter.isdigit():
            return [item[:index],item[index:]]

print(text_num_split("foobar12345"))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['foobar', '12345']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

s = raw_input()
m = re.match(r"([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)",s)
print m.group(0)
print m.group(1)
print m.group(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution for that problem, no need for `regex`:

```
user = input('Input: ') # user = 'foobar12345'
int_list, str_list = [], []

for item in user:
 try:
    item = int(item)  # searching for integers in your string
  except:
    str_list.append(item)
    string = ''.join(str_list)
  else:  # if there are integers i will add it to int_list but as str, because join function only can work with str
    int_list.append(str(item))
    integer = int(''.join(int_list))  # if you want it to be string just do z = ''.join(int_list)

final = [string, integer]  # you can also add it to dictionary d = {string: integer}
print(final)
```

Comment: are you sure this is correct `item = int(item)  # searching for integers in your string`!!!!???

Answer (score 0):

This is a little longer, but more versatile for cases where there are multiple, randomly placed, numbers in the string. Also, it requires no imports.

```
def getNumbers( input ):
    # Collect Info
    compile = ""
    complete = []

    for letter in input:
        # If compiled string
        if compile:
            # If compiled and letter are same type, append letter
            if compile.isdigit() == letter.isdigit():
                compile += letter
            
            # If compiled and letter are different types, append compiled string, and begin with letter
            else:
                complete.append( compile )
                compile = letter
            
        # If no compiled string, begin with letter
        else:
            compile = letter
        
    # Append leftover compiled string
    if compile:
        complete.append( compile )
    
    # Return numbers only
    numbers = [ word for word in complete if word.isdigit() ]
        
    return numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the answer of @Evan
If the incoming string is in this pattern `21foofo` then the `re.match` pattern would be like this.

```
import re
match = re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-z]+)", '21foofo', re.I)
if match:
    items = match.groups()
print(items)
>> ("21", "foofo")
```

Otherwise, you'll get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'items' referenced before assignment` error.

Answer (score 0):

According to your use case, you might have luck with the `re.split()` method:

[re.split()](https://pynative.com/python-regex-split/)

With that I could extract the "average" duration of a dataset like

```
< 1 minute
240 - 480 minutes
120 - 240 minutes
60 - 120 minutes
50 - 60 minutes
```

```py
import re

def avg_duration(s):
    # duration as a human string, converted to a float
    values = [float(x) for x in re.split(r"\D+", s) if len(x) > 0]
    # Return average
    return sum(values) / len(values)
```

Not that I needed a `if len(x) > 0` clause for this, as there are many "empty" groups with this approach but otherwise it worked very well.