# Naturally sort a list of alpha-numeric tuples by the tuple's first element in Python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, alphanumeric, natural-sort

A [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python) explains how to sort a list of strings alpha-numerically.  I would like to sort a list of tuples alphanumerically by the tuple's first element.

Example 1:

```
>>> sort_naturally_tuple([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)])
[('0', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 0)]
```

Example 2:

```
>>> sort_naturally_tuple([('b10', 0), ('0', 1), ('b9', 2)])
[('0', 1), ('b9', 2), ('b10', 0)]
```

**Update:**  To emphasize the alphanumeric factor, please review example 2.

Comment: It's spelled `sorted()` and works exactly like that (except it returns a generator instead of a list).

Comment: @Kirk `sorted` returns a list no matter the input (iter, tuple, genexp) ...

Comment: @JBernardo You're right, of course. I was thinking of `reversed` and wrote that before verifying. My apologies if I confused anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the second answer from the other question, generalized to support any method on item as the basis for getting the key:

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter

def sorted_nicely(l, key):
    """ Sort the given iterable in the way that humans expect."""
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda item: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key(item)) ]
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)


print sorted_nicely([('b10', 0), ('0', 1), ('b9', 2)], itemgetter(0))
```

This is exactly the same as that answer except generalized to use **any callable** as the operation on item. If you just wanted to do it on a string, you'd use `lambda item: item`, if you wanted to do it on a list, tuple, dict, or set, you'd use `operator.itemgetter(key_or_index_you_want)`, or if you wanted to do it on a class instance you could use `operator.attrgetter('attribute_name_you_want')`.

It gives

```
[('0', 1), ('b9', 2), ('b10', 0)]
```

for your example #2.

Comment: sure, just change `key[0]` to `key['thekeyyouwanttosortby']`

Comment: Easy! Hmm, how about a step further?  Would it be possible to send the `sorted_nicely()` method what you want to sort by?  For example `sorted_nicely(l, 'key[0]')` would sort by first element in `l`.  Another example is `sorted_nicely(d, 'key[\'the_key_you_want_to_sort_by\')'` would sort dictionary `d` by element `d['the_key_you_want_to_sort_by']`.

Comment: This is perfecto.  Now I can use this for dictionaries, lists, & tuples!

Answer (score 4):

Tuples are by default sorted by their elements, starting at the first. So simply do

```
L = [('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)]
L.sort()
print L
# or create a new, sorted list
print sorted([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)])
```

The question you liked to talks about natural sorting, which is different from normal (alphanumeric) sorting.

Lets say you want to do natural sort on the first item only:

```
import re
def naturalize(item):
    # turn 'b10' into ('b',10) which sorts correctly
    m = re.match(r'(\w+?)(\d+)', item)
    return m.groups()
# now sort by using this function on the first element of the tuple:
print sorted(L, key=lambda tup: naturalize(tup[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks.  My apologies, I did not emphasize the natural sort.  `sorted([('b10', 0), ('0', 1), ('b9', 2)])` returns `[('0', 1), ('b10', 0), ('b9', 2)]`, which is incorrect as `('b9', 2)` should precede `('b10', 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, sorted will use the first element of the tuple by default.  If you wish to modify this default behavior you can specify a key to be used during the comparisons.

```
sorted([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)])
```

Will return the same as:

```
sorted([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)], key=lambda item: item[0])
```

To sort by the second element however try:

```
sorted([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)], key=lambda item: item[1])
```

Comment: Use `operator.itemgetter` for this method, not a lambda.

Comment: Wasn't aware of this.  So something akin to sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(1)(arr)) to sort by the second element?  Thanks btw

Comment: Thanks.  My apologies, I did not emphasize the natural sort.  `sorted([('b10', 0), ('0', 1), ('b9', 2)])` returns `[('0', 1), ('b10', 0), ('b9', 2)]`, which is incorrect as `('b9', 2)` should precede `('b10', 0)`.

Comment: `from operator import itemgetter; sorted([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)], key=itemgetter(1))`

Comment: `sorted([('b10', 0), ('0', 1), ('b9', 2)], key=lambda item: item[0])` returns `[('0', 1), ('b10', 0), ('b9', 2)]`, which is incorrect as `('b9', 2)` should precede `('b10', 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) module does this by default without any extra work

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> natsorted([('b', 0), ('0', 1), ('a', 2)])
[('0', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 0)]
>>> natsorted([('b10', 0), ('0', 1), ('b9', 2)])
[('0', 1), ('b9', 2), ('b10', 0)]
```