# How to order a python list of "string" numbers by its value

Tags: python, list

I have this list of files:

```
1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., 10.jpg, ...
```

If I do a python **os.listdir(".")** i have all files listed but in alphabetical order like this:

```
[1.jpg, 10.jpg, 11.jpg, ..., 2.jpg, 20.jpg....]
```

But I want them ordered by its numerical value

```
[1.jpg, 2.jpg ,...10 ,11 ,12... ]
```

How do I reorder the list to have this done?

tx

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150239/python-natural-sorting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849047/naturally-sort-a-list-of-alpha-numeric-tuples-by-the-tuples-first-element-in-py and 1999+ similar questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [51]: lis=["1.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","2.jpg","20.jpg"]

In [52]: sorted(lis,key=lambda x:int(x.split(".")[0]))
Out[52]: ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '10.jpg', '11.jpg', '20.jpg']
```

Comment: I think you might as well just copy paste from the other answer :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes the time difference between both answers is hardly 1 min. :)

Comment: @butelo glad that helped. you can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: of course, the system forces me to wait some minutes. I'll accept your answer ASAP