# sort files in a specific order

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I want to know how I can sort the filenames as they are in the directory. For example, I have the following names:

```
1_00000_6.54.csv
2_00000_1.70.csv
3_00000_1.70.csv
...
10_00000_1.70.csv
11_00000_1.70.csv
...
```

With the following python code I get the following order:

```
 def get_pixelist(path):
     return [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

 def group_uniqmz_intensities(path):
     pxlist = sorted(get_pixelist(path))
```

gives:

```
1_00000_6.54.csv
10_00000_1.70.csv
11_00000_1.70
...
2_00000_1.70.csv
...
3_00000_1.70.csv
...
```

I want the order shown before.

Comment: Good question. What you're asking is sometimes referred to as the ["natural sort order"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html); it would make sense to make a Python `key` for that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to zero-pad the filenames when sorting:

```
def group_uniqmz_intensities(path):
    pxlist = sorted(get_pixelist(path), key=lambda f: f.rjust(17, '0'))
```

which will pad each filename to 17 characters with `0` characters when sorting; so `1_00000_6.54.csv` is padded to `01_00000_6.54.csv` while `10_00000_1.70.csv` is left as is. Lexographically, `01` sorts before `10`.

I picked 17 as a hardcoded value to simplify things; you could find the required value automatically by using this instead:

```
def group_uniqmz_intensities(path):
    padsize = max(len(f) for f in pxlist)
    pxlist = sorted(get_pixelist(path), key=lambda f: f.rjust(padsize, '0'))
```

Comment: Nice one! To make sure it works properly 17 should be changed to length of the longest filename. Something like max_length = len(max(get_pixelist(path), key=lambda x: len(x)) .

Comment: I'd use `str.zfill` instead of `str.rjust`

Comment: thanks Martijn. This is not what I want. I want the following order: 1_00000_6.54.csv
2_00000_1.70.csv
3_00000_1.70.csv
...
10_00000_1.70.csv
11_00000_1.70.csv

Comment: @HocineBen That's exactly what you obtain with this solution.

Comment: @HocineBen see my comment above. Try changing 17 to 25 (or some big number) and see if it helps.

Comment: I get this (with the solution):  10_00000_6.54.csv
11_00000_1.70.csv
1_00000_1.70
...
2_00000_1.70.csv
...
3_00000_1.70.csv

Comment: @Bakuriu: You could do that too; we don't need to handle signs (`-` or `+` here) so using `.rjust` is probably slightly faster.

Comment: @HocineBen: it could be that I miscounted; use a higher number than 17 or determine the length automatically with using the `max()` line I added.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Testing a bit with `timeit` it seems `zfill` is slightly *faster* than `rjust`. At least in python2.7.3 on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Since '1' < '_' you get the second ordering. You can achieve your goal by giving a key-function to sorted:

```
 def group_uniqmz_intensities(path):
     pxlist = sorted(get_pixelist(path), key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[0]))
```

Please make sure ALL of your files are following the same naming scheme ({number}_{rest}.csv) otherwise there will be a ValueError.

EDIT: Martijn Pieters provides a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669523/50065) for alphanumerical sorting:

```
def group_uniqmz_intensities(path):
    pxlist = sorted(get_pixelist(path), key=lambda filename: int(filename.partition('_')[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial implementation of natural ordering, assuming that your fields are all split by `_`:

```
def int_if_possible(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s


>>> sorted(s, key=lambda s: map(int_if_possible, s.split('_')))
['1_00000_6.54.csv',
 '2_00000_1.70.csv',
 '3_00000_1.70.csv',
 '10_00000_1.70.csv',
 '11_00000_1.70.csv']
```

This implementation leverages the fact that lists get compared element-by-element. If the elements are convertible to ints, we compare them as ints, otherwise we fall back to string comparison.

---

**Edit**: A more elaborate solution for natural sorting is presented here: [Natural string sorting](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285264-natural-string-sorting/).

It's pretty clever: it uses a regex `\d+\D+` to split input strings into alternating numbers and non-numbers. Then numbers are compared numerically, and non-numbers alphabetically.