# What is the best way to sort this list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
my_list = ['name.13','name.1', 'name.2','name.4', 'name.32']
```

And I would like sort the list and print it out in order, like this

```
name.1
name.2
name.4
name.13
name.32
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
print sorted(my_list)

name.1
name.13
name.2
name.32
name.4
```

The sorted() command obviously treats the string alphabetically. Maybe it would be better to sort numerically after detecting the `.` first?

Is there an good way to sort it properly? What would be the most efficient approach to take? How would I apply this is I had a list of tuples and wanted to sort it using the second elemnt of the tuples? For instance:

```
tuple_list = [('i','name.2'),('t','name.13'),('s','name.32'),('l','name.1'),('s','name.4')]

print tuple_list
'l','name.1'
'i','name.2'
's','name.4'
't','name.13'
's','name.32'
```

Thanks for your help and, as always, comment if you think the question can be improved/clarified.

Alex

Comment: Is the text before the period always the same (i.e. 'name')? If not, how do you want to sort items with different names?

Comment: The text is always 'name.' followed by a number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort alpha numeric set in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try it similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669523/2280602) answer:

```
>>> my_list = ['name.13','name.1', 'name.2','name.4', 'name.32']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda a: (int(a.split('.')[1])))
['name.1', 'name.2', 'name.4', 'name.13', 'name.32']
```

Or with tuples:

```
>>> tuple_list = [('i','name.2'),('t','name.13'),('s','name.32'),('l','name.1'),('s','name.4')]
>>> sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda (a,b): (int(b.split('.')[1])))
[('l', 'name.1'), ('i', 'name.2'), ('s', 'name.4'), ('t', 'name.13'), ('s', 'name.32')]
```

**Edit** to explain what this does:

The example passes a lambda function to `sorted` that splits the strings and then converts the second part to an integer. `sorted` then uses this integer to sort the list items.

This example completely ignores the strings to the left of the dot when sorting. Please let me know if you also need to sort by the first part.

Comment: This is a cool solution! Thanks - how would it be adapted to cope with the list of tuples situation posted in the question edit?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As of [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) version 4.0.0, this works out of the box without having to specify any options:

```
>>> import natsort
>>> my_list = ['name.13','name.1', 'name.2','name.4', 'name.32']
>>> natsort.natsorted(my_list)
['name.1','name.2', 'name.4','name.13', 'name.32']
```

---

**OLD ANSWER** for natsort < 4.0.0

If you do not object to external packages, try the [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) package (version >= 3.0.0):

```
>>> import natsort
>>> my_list = ['name.13','name.1', 'name.2','name.4', 'name.32']
>>> natsort.natsorted(my_list, number_type=int)
['name.1','name.2', 'name.4','name.13', 'name.32']
```

The `number_type` argument is necessary in this case because `natsort` by default looks for floats, and the decimal point would make all these numbers be interpreted as floats.

---

Full disclosure: I am the `natsort` author.

Comment: I do not object, this is very useful! So to cope with the list of tuples situation, I would do `natsort.natsorted(my_list[1])` ?

Comment: I'm glad you like it!  Yes, that should work for a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[1]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = ['name.13','name.1', 'name.2','name.4', 'name.32']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[1]))
['name.1', 'name.2', 'name.4', 'name.13', 'name.32']
>>>
```

Extending it to the tuple,

```
sorted(tuple_list, key = lambda x: int(x[1].split('.')[1]))
```

DEMO:

```
>>> sorted(tuple_list, key = lambda x: int(x[1].split('.')[1]))
[('l', 'name.1'), ('i', 'name.2'), ('s', 'name.4'), ('t', 'name.13'), ('s', 'name.32')]
```

Comment: @karthikr It doesn't sort numerically as per the question.

Comment: Oh snap.. I misread the question. Shall delete the answer when the system allows me to.

Comment: How would one adapt this to cope with the question edit? i.e. a list of tuples?

Answer (score 3):

This one uses more memory but does not split each item multiple times:

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_list = ['name.13','name.1', 'name.2','name.4', 'name.32']
my_nlist= [ (int(n.split('.')[1]), i) for i,n in enumerate(my_list)]
my_list = [ my_list[t[1]] for t in sorted(my_nlist, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

to deal with tuples:

```
my_list = [('i','name.2'),('t','name.13'),
           ('s','name.32'),('l','name.1'),('s','name.4')]
my_nlist= [ (int(n[1].split('.')[1]), i) for i,n in enumerate(my_list)]
my_list = [ my_list[t[1]] for t in sorted(my_nlist, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Comment: An interesting approach, how would it cope with the list of tuples situation in the question edit?