# python dictionary function, textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to define a function `scaryDict()` which takes one parameter (a `textfile`) and returns the words from the `textfile` in alphabetical order, basically produce a dictionary but does not print any one or two letter words.

Here is what I have so far...it isn't much but I don't know the next step

```
def scaryDict(fineName):

    inFile = open(fileName,'r')
    lines = inFile.read()
    line = lines.split()
    myDict = {}
    for word in inFile:
        myDict[words] = []
        #I am not sure what goes between the line above and below
    for x in lines:
        print(word, end='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine till `line = lines.split()`. But your for loop must loop through the line array, not the `inFile`.

```
for word in line:
    if len(word) > 2: # Make sure to check the word length!
        myDict[word] = 'something'
```

I'm not sure what you want with the dictionary (maybe get the word count?), but once you have it, you can get the words you added to it by,

```
allWords = myDict.keys() # so allWords is now a list of words
```

And then you can sort `allWords` to get them in alphabetical order.

```
allWords.sort()
```

Comment: I have to fill an empty dictionary with words from a textfile in an alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

I would store all of the words into a set (to eliminate dups), then sort that set:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def scaryDict(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as inFile:
         return sorted(set(word
                          for line in inFile
                          for word in line.split()
                          if len(word) > 2))

scaryWords = scaryDict('frankenstein.txt')
print ('\n'.join(scaryWords))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind as of 2.5 the 'with' file contains an **enter** and **exit** methods which can prevent some issues (such as that file never getting closed)

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

Unique [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python)

Sort the [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python)

Now you can put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that i am 3 years late : ) here is my version

```
def scaryDict():
    infile = open('filename', 'r') 
    content = infile.read()
    infile.close()

    table = str.maketrans('.`/()|,\';!:"?=-', 15 * ' ')
    content = content.translate(table)

    words = content.split()
    new_words = list()

    for word in words:
        if len(word) > 2:
            new_words.append(word)

    new_words = list(set(new_words))
    new_words.sort()

    for word in new_words:
        print(word)
```