# Sorting list of strings like [3a, 13a, 5a, 11a] by numeric value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to sort a list with numbers and letter by numeric value.

```
list = ['3a', '13a', '5a', '11a']
```

When I use the .sort function it sorts it like this:

```
['11a', '13a', '3a', '5a']
```

Like it's only looking at the first number.

Comment: What did you try? Yes, they're strings, they will be sorted lexicographically.

Comment: This sort is base on character

Comment: There is similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669120/5916727

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort alpha numeric set in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a lambda for a sorting key.

```
list = ['3a', '13a', '5a', '11a']
list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[:-1]))
```

The important part is:

```
lambda x: int(x[:-1])
```

which takes in a string, removes the last character, and converts it to an integer.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/KHmV)

Comment: Fixed the try it online link.

Comment: Your proposal is unsafe. There may be more that one letter - or no letter at all.

Comment: @DYZ The OP specified that the list contained things like this, so I did it. Of course, if it might not, it is best to do some checks beforehand.

Comment: "Like" does not mean "exactly."

Comment: @JoshForcier Of all the answers you could have accepted, I would recommend this the least. It works specifically for your single case and nothing more.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. It looks like using natural sort would be the best, but for my purposes I can't use import.

Answer (score 4):

If you just use an unmodified `sorted` it will sort on the ASCII codes on each character in the string:

```
>>> sorted(['2','11','01000'])
['01000', '11', '2']
```

vs adding a key value that tells `sorted` to use the integer value:

```
>>> sorted(['2','11','01000'], key=int)
['2', '11', '01000']
```

For strings that are a mixture of integers and letters, use a [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) where letters are sorted lexicographically and numbers are treated to simple integer comparison:

```
import re

def natural_sort(l): 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

>>> li = ['3a', '13a', '5a', '11a']
>>> natural_sort(li)
['3a', '5a', '11a', '13a']
```

The advantage of this version is it handles multiple groups of numbers and letters:

```
>>> li = ['3a33', '3a2', '3b1', '3a1', '5a', '11a']
>>> natural_sort(li)
['3a1', '3a2', '3a33', '3b1', '5a', '11a']
```

As well as what you would expect with the letters in front:

```
>>> li = ['a33', 'a2', 'b1', 'a1', 'a', 'a00004']
>>> natural_sort(li)
['a', 'a1', 'a2', 'a00004', 'a33', 'b1']
```

(PS: Best to not call a python list `list` because it stomps on the name of the function...)

Answer (score 2):

Your list is a list of strings. So `list.sort` will sort the elements lexicographically. You can change this by passing a key to your sorting function. You can use `re.match` (`import re` first) to extract the digits and compare. Something like this:

```
In [30]: list_ = ['3a', '13a', '5a', '11a']

In [31]: matcher = re.compile('\d+')

In [32]: sorted(list_, key=lambda x: int(matcher.match(x).group()))
Out[32]: ['3a', '5a', '11a', '13a']
```

This works best if your elements have something more than `a` at the end of them.

Comment: This sorts on the first number captured only as a use note.

Answer (score 1):

There is package called `natsort`

```
from natsort import natsorted
LL = ['3a', '13a', '5a', '11a']
natsorted(LL)

Out[296]: ['3a', '5a', '11a', '13a']
```

@dawg's example using `natsort`:

```
li = ['3a33', '3a2', '3a1', '13a', '5a', '11a']

natsorted(li)
Out[298]: ['3a1', '3a2', '3a33', '5a', '11a', '13a']
```