# Ordering file in list by pattern python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list with 240 figures all starting with the fig and the number of the fig.

Here is an example :

```
fig1-24-24-32
fig3-45-32-12
fig2-24-24-31
fig5-24-24-31
fig6-24-24-31
fig4-24-24-31
```

I would like to order that list by fig name:

```
fig1-24-24-32
fig2-24-24-31
fig3-45-32-12
fig4-24-24-31
fig5-24-24-31
fig6-24-24-31
```

I have tried :

```
print(glob.glob('fig*[1-241]*'))
```

However this does not work
This is what I get[image: output]

UPDATE
Found the answer to my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669120/6235069 Answer is given by @Mark Byers

Comment: Have you considered `sorted(your_list)`?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming here that all the files start with the same 3-character long prefix ( does not have to be `'fig'`; will not be taken into account) which in turn is followed by digits (*one or many*) until a dash (`'-'`) is met.

If that is indeed the case, you can use the following:

```
sorted(my_files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0][3:]))
```

Note that `my_files` is a list containing all the filenames (*basenames*).

Output:

```
['fig1-24-24-32', 
 'fig2-24-24-31', 
 'fig3-45-32-12', 
 'fig4-24-24-31', 
 'fig5-24-24-31', 
 'fig6-24-24-31']
```

Comment: Thank you the logical explantation seems right however I have this error when running the script over my 240 figures: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ig144'

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do you job:

```
mylist=['fig1-24-24-32',
'fig3-45-32-12',
'fig2-24-24-31',
'fig5-24-24-31',
'fig6-24-24-31',
'fig4-24-24-31']

updated_list=sorted(mylist)
```

Sorted will do your job until and unless you want to sort on the first 3 characters.

```
updated_list

['fig1-24-24-32',
 'fig2-24-24-31',
 'fig3-45-32-12',
 'fig4-24-24-31',
 'fig5-24-24-31',
 'fig6-24-24-31']
```