# Using os.walk to move through a directory and execute a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab, os.walk

Currently I am working on a project which will take however many folders and merge the contents of each folder into a pdf. Meaning each folder will output one pdf. I was able to figure out how to merge the files I'm working with into a singular pdf using ReportLab. Now I need to have it iterate through each folder and create a pdf. So far I am able to use os.walk to run through my test directories but it wont run the pdf script.

```
import glob
import os
import re
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Image, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

list_of_files = ["C:\\foo_1", "C:\\foo_2"]    

os.chdir("C:\\foo")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
   for name in files: 
      print(os.path.join(root, name)) #used to see where os.walk is working
      def sorted_nicely( l ):
        """ 
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python
        Sort the given iterable in the way that humans expect.
        """ 
        convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 
        alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
        return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)

      def collect_issue(fname):
            if not fname.endswith(".pdf"):
                fname += ".pdf"
                doc = SimpleDocTemplate(fname,pagesize=letter,
                                        rightMargin=0,leftMargin=0,
                                        topMargin=0,bottomMargin=0)
                width = 7.5*inch
                height = 9.5*inch    

                picture_file_names = sorted_nicely(glob.glob("*.jp2"))
                contents = []
                for pic_fname in picture_file_names:
                    im = Image(pic_fname, width=width, height=height)
                    contents.append(im)
                    contents.append(PageBreak())
                doc.build(contents)

      if __name__ == "__main__":
            collect_issue("test")
```

I am looking specifically for help using os.walk to have the pdf script run through however many folders I need. I'm not entirely sure what exactly is causing it not to work either. For reference, a lot of this code is based of of [this script](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/01/07/reportlab-converting-hundreds-of-images-into-pdfs/).

Comment: Your code indentation is off - you missed a `"` thats why all your code was red. . the   `if __name__ == ... ` should be at the 0 indentation lvl , your functions probably as well. Please fix.-

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you for the edit and feedback. I'm embarrassed that I missed a `"`, locally I have my actual file locations and this issue wasn't present. I edited the indentation levels locally and it unfortunately didn't cause it to work. Idle also forces the indentation after the `print(os.path.join(...))` so I that's why the indentation is as is above.

Comment: We cant help you then - pythons indentation is important for forming execution blocks. Try to copy _your sources_ , paste them into the question, select them and hit Ctrl+k to format as code

Comment: @PatrickArtner The code is formatted just like I have it locally sans original directory paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an overall inelegant solution but it suffices and solved my original question.

```
import glob
import os
import re
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Image, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.units import inch


os.chdir("C:\\Foo")
file_num = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
    def collect_issue(fname):
        if not fname.endswith(".pdf"):
            fname += ".pdf"
            doc = SimpleDocTemplate(fname,pagesize=letter,
                  rightMargin=0,leftMargin=0,
                  topMargin=0,bottomMargin=0)
            width = 7.5*inch
            height = 9.5*inch    

            contents = []
            print(root)
            for name in files: 
                im = Image(root + "\\" + name, width, height)

                contents.append(im)
                contents.append(PageBreak())
            if contents:
                doc.build(contents)       

    collect_issue("test" + str(file_num))
    file_num += 1
```