# How can I sort this list numerically?

Tags: python, python-3.7

How do I sort this list numerically?

```
sa = ['3 :mat', '20 :zap', '20 :jhon', '5 :dave', '14 :maya' ]
print(sorted(sa))
```

This shows

```
[ '14 :maya', '20 :zap','20 :jhon', '3 :mat', '5 :dave']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort alpha numeric set in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, since your numbers are part a the string:

```
sorted(sa, key = lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below, which will use the numbers in the string and sort them.

```
sa.sort(key=lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))))
print(sa)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `regex`:

```
sorted(sa, key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+', x)[0]))
```

---

```
['3 :mat', '5 :dave', '14 :maya', '20 :zap', '20 :jhon']
```

Using module `natsort`

```
from natsort import natsorted
natsorted(sa)
```

---

```
['3 :mat', '5 :dave', '14 :maya', '20 :jhon', '20 :zap']
```