# Sorting a text files in numerical order (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

[Description of the script problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iqly.png)

Hello,
I am new using Python, and I have a problem sorting my files.
I have multiple files in text format from 0 to 20 but when I sort them they are coming in this order : 0, 1, 11, 12 ... despite of 0, 1, 2, 3 ...
I tried multiple things found here but it is not working.
Could you help me, please?

```
data_dir = 'Data_CO2/'
folder = '01-15-2020-B/'
dir_folder = data_dir+folder
files = os.listdir(dir_folder)
files_20 = []
for ff in files:
    if 'TPD' in ff: 
        files_20.append(ff)

files_20.sort()
files_20 

Output : 
'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-0.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-1.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-10.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-11.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-12.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-13.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-14.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-15.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-16.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-17.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-18.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-19.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-2.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-20.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-3.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-4.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-5.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-6.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-7.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-8.DPT',
 'TPD at 1K.min from 26K to 120K-CsI 335deg, 1cm-1, 64 scans -CO2 CH4 mix -01-15-2020-9.DPT'
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669059/7207392

Comment: Hi! Please include the code/error messages as text and not as an image.

Comment: It looks like the default sort for files is alphabetical order. I have run into similar problems with the unix comand `sort`. I'm not familiar with working with files in python, but I would expect you can pass in a different comparison function when you call sort.

Answer (score 2):

Because `sort` is being handled a bunch of strings, it will sort alphabetically. If you want to sort based on the "index" instead, you can do:

```
def get_index(file_name: str):
    indexed_extension = file_name.split("-")[-1]
    index = indexed_extension.split(".")[0]

    return int(index)
```

followed by

```
files_20.sort(key=get_index)
```

This will work for any date (not just `01-15-2020`). It relies on the file name having a `-<index>.<extension>` at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I understand now, thanks !

Comment: @AlexiaSimon No problem, since this answer helped you can press the green checkmark to the left to accept it.