# Sorting Dataframe Columns By Alphabetical & Numerical Order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, reindex

I would like to re-index the columns of a dataframe by sorting them by both alphabetical order and numerical order.

In my dataframe df, my columns are named:

> Round 1 Position, Round 2 Position, Round 1 Score, Round 2 Score, Round 1 Price, Round 2 Price, ...,  Round 10 Position, Round 10 Score, Round 10 Price

I would like them to be ordered as follows:

> Round 1 Position, Round 1 Price, Round 1 Score, Round 2 Position, Round 2 Price, Round 2 Score, Round 3 Position, Round 3 Price, Round 3 Score, ...,  Round 10 Position, Round 10 Price, Round 10 Score

I have tried the following:

```
df.reindex(sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: float(x[1:])), axis=1)
```

but had no luck as the column name was a string.

Thank you for taking the time to read through my question and help me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you sort the column names into their natural order, you can use `[]` indexing to re-order the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import natsort

df = pd.DataFrame({'A2': [1, 2, 3],
               'B1': [4, 5, 6],
               'A1': [7, 8, 9]})

# sort the column names
col_names = df.columns
sorted_col_names = natsort.natsorted(col_names)

# re-order the columns
df = df[sorted_col_names]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A1  A2  B1
0   7   1   4
1   8   2   5
2   9   3   6
```

---

There are several options for sorting alpha-numeric values in the answers to [How to sort alpha numeric set in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669059/1288). I tested the `natsort` library, and it works with your input.

```
columns = ['Round 1 Position', 'Round 2 Position', 'Round 1 Score', 'Round 2 Score', 'Round 1 Price',
           'Round 2 Price', 'Round 10 Position', 'Round 10 Score', 'Round 10 Price']
columns_s = natsort.natsorted(columns)
print(columns_s)
```

Output:

```
['Round 1 Position', 'Round 1 Price', 'Round 1 Score', 'Round 2 Position', 'Round 2 Price', 'Round 2 Score', 'Round 10 Position', 'Round 10 Price', 'Round 10 Score']
```