# how do I separate a string that contains number

Tags: python, string, split

So, I have this string:
a='test32'
I want to separate this string so I get the text and the number in two separate variables, in python .

Comment: `var1,var2 = (a[:4], a[4:])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split strings into text and number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
r = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
>>> m=r.match('test32')
>>> m.group(1)
'test'
>>> m.group(2)
'32'
>>>
```