# how i can split word and number after scraping website with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

It's look difficult to me to scrap data from website and that data is inside a table. I use BeautifulSoup and urllib from Python and when i run the program, it's look like this `IndexAceh5.82Bali6.23Banten5.85Bengkulu4.81DKI6.`. How i can remove `Index`, split word like `Aceh` and number `5.82` into something like  this

```
prov = ['Aceh', 'Bali']

number = [5.82, 6.23]
```

and this is my code and website link :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = "MY LINK"
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
pemerintah = soup.find("table", attrs={"cellspacing": "0"}); #cellspacing="0"
name = pemerintah.text.strip()
print name
```

I found same case in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number), but when i try, it not working because on my case i have `.` and if i use `ade12.3` for example it will give me result `ade, 12`, not `ade, 12.3`

Comment: You most likely want to loop over the TR elements of your table and then access its TD elements instead of taking the text from the table as one big item and then trying to post-parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `th` & `td` tags to search.

**Ex:**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = "http://www.kemitraan.or.id/igi/index.php/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=235"
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
pemerintah = soup.find("table", attrs={"cellspacing": "0"}); #cellspacing="0"
for i in pemerintah.find_all("tr"):
    if i.find("th"):
        print i.th.text, " = ", i.td.text
```

**Output:**

```
Aceh  =  5.82
Bali  =  6.23
Banten  =  5.85
Bengkulu  =  4.81
....
```

Comment: `for i in pemerintah.find_all("tr")[1:]:`  You can slice the first item from the list

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to get the values you want with BS4. But if you want to work with strings, you can use re.

```
import re

y = 'IndexAceh5.82Bali6.23Banten5.85Bengkulu4.81'
k = re.split('(\w+)(\d.?\.\d.?)', y.replace('Index',''))
k = [i for i in k if i] #removes ‘’
prov = [item for i,item in enumerate(k) if i%2==0]
num  = [item for i,item in enumerate(k) if i%2!=0]

del y,k,i,item #cleaning
```