# How to split a column into alphabetic values and numeric values from a column in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe:

```
    Name    Section
1   James   P3
2   Sam     2.5C
3   Billy   T35
4   Sarah   A85
5   Felix   5I
```

How do I split numeric values into a separate column called Section_Number and also split alphabetic values to Section_Letter.
Desired results

```
    Name    Section Section_Number  Section_Letter
1   James   P3               3          P
2   Sam     2.5C           2.5          C
3   Billy   T35             35          T
4   Sarah   A85             85          A
5   Felix   5L               5          L
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by `[A-Z]+` for all uppercase strings:

```
df['Section_Number'] = df['Section'].str.replace('([A-Z]+)', '')
df['Section_Letter'] = df['Section'].str.extract('([A-Z]+)')
print (df)
    Name Section Section_Number Section_Letter
1  James      P3              3              P
2    Sam    2.5C            2.5              C
3  Billy     T35             35              T
4  Sarah     A85             85              A
5  Felix      5I              5              I
```

For seelct also lowercase values:

```
df['Section_Number'] = df['Section'].str.replace('([A-Za-z]+)', '')
df['Section_Letter'] = df['Section'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)')
print (df)
    Name Section Section_Number Section_Letter
1  James      P3              3              P
2    Sam    2.5C            2.5              C
3  Billy     T35             35              T
4  Sarah     A85             85              A
5  Felix      5I              5              I
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll no doubt be slower but throwing out an alternative for completeness you can use `str.extractall` to get named groups matching the patterns and consolidate the matches and join back to your DF...

```
new = df.join(
    df.Section.str.extractall(r'(?i)(?P<Section_Letter>[A-Z]+)|(?P<Section_Number>[\d.]+)')
    .groupby(level=0).first()
)
```

Result:

```
    Name Section Section_Letter Section_Number
1  James      P3              P              3
2    Sam    2.5C              C            2.5
3  Billy     T35              T             35
4  Sarah     A85              A             85
5  Felix      5I              I              5
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as in your example, you have one letter in each name, you can sort and then slice:

```
def get_vals(x):
    return ''.join(sorted(x, key=str.isalpha))

# apply ordering
vals = df['Section'].apply(get_vals)

# split numbers from letter
df['num'] = vals.str[:-1].astype(float)
df['letter'] = vals.str[-1]

print(df)

    Name Section   num letter
1  James      P3   3.0      P
2    Sam    2.5C   2.5      C
3  Billy     T35  35.0      T
4  Sarah     A85  85.0      A
5  Felix      5I   5.0      I
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `itertools.groupby` to group the contiguous alpha and non-alpha

```
from itertools import groupby

[sorted([''.join(x) for _, x in groupby(s, key=str.isalpha)]) for s in df.Section]

[['3', 'P'], ['2.5', 'C'], ['35', 'T'], ['85', 'A'], ['5', 'I']]
```

We can manipulate this into new columns

```
from itertools import groupby

N, L = zip(
    *[sorted([''.join(x) for _, x in groupby(s, key=str.isalpha)]) for s in df.Section]
)
df.assign(Selection_Number=N, Selection_Letter=L)

    Name Section Selection_Number Selection_Letter
1  James      P3                3                P
2    Sam    2.5C              2.5                C
3  Billy     T35               35                T
4  Sarah     A85               85                A
5  Felix      5I                5                I
```