# Python split currency string into currency code and amount

Tags: python-3.x, string, algorithm

I am trying to split `R15.49 to (R, 15.49)` or

`ZAR15.49 to (ZAR, 15.49)`

I have tried one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number) and implememted the function below:

```
def splitCurrency(string):    
    match = re.search(r'([\D]+)([\d,]+)', string)
    output = (match.group(1), match.group(2).replace(',',''))
    return output
```

But I am getting (R, 15) or (ZAR, 15). and its ignoring the digits after the decimal place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fish out these values from a larger text, then use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "R15.49 or ZAR15.49"
matches = re.findall(r'\b([A-Z]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('R', '15.49'), ('ZAR', '15.49')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually your first answer before your edit is what I am looking for. I guess my wording was a bit confusing and I have edited the question

Comment: By it is still resulting in an error 'unterminated subpattern at position 0'. If you can please review your first answer. Thanks

Comment: Reload the page.  My initial suggestion to use `re.split` is not viable.  The code you see above has been tested and is working.