# Regex split numbers and letter groups without spaces with python

Tags: python

I have a string like 'S10', 'S11' v.v
How to split this to ['S','10'], ['S','11']
example:

```
import re
str = 'S10'
re.compile(...)
result = re.split(str)
```

result:

```
print(result)
// ['S','10']
```

resolved at [How to split strings into text and number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number/430102#430102)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/430102/12420884

Comment: What are you trying to split exactly? letters from numbers? usually when you split there is some common thing between each thing your splitting (such as "\n", ",", ".", etc)

Comment: oh it's resolved :D tks @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to an answer

Comment: @XuânTrọng please mark this question as a duplicate if the link helped you solve your problem

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ok, I will do it from next time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

I'm using capture groups using the circle brackets to match the alphabetical part to the first group and the numbers to the second group.

Code:

```
import re

str_data = 'S10'
exp = "(\w)(\d+)"
match = re.match(exp, str_data)
result = match.groups()
```

Output:

```
('S', '10')
```