# Separate a word from a number python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with 1 column containing the amount bought of a particular crypto

```
df['Amount'] = 200.20356AVAX
```

I would like to split this object into 2 columns:

- 1 containing the number --> `df['Quantity'] = 200.20356`
- 1 containing the word --> `df['Asset'] = AVAX`

Comment: I doubt that line of code is valid Python... are you sure it's not a string?

Comment: Have you _tried something_? There are many [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split strings into text and number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number)

Comment: parse the string '200.20356AVAX' using a regular expression to separate digits from alpha

Comment: As stated below by @Corralien 

df = df.join(df['Amount'].str.extract('([^A-Z]+)([A-Z]+)') \
                         .rename(columns={0: 'Quantity', 1: 'Asset'}))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': ['200.20356AVAX']})

df = df.join(df['Amount'].str.extract('([^A-Z]+)([A-Z]+)') \
                         .rename(columns={0: 'Quantity', 1: 'Asset'}))

# OR, proposed by @mozway (more efficient)

df = df.join(df['Amount'].str.extract('(?P<Quantity>[^A-Z]+)(?P<Asset>[A-Z]+)'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          Amount   Quantity Asset
0  200.20356AVAX  200.20356  AVAX
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a brilliant solution!

Comment: @Corralien you should use named capturing groups ;)

Comment: Really? Does it work???

Comment: @mozway. When I think about the number of times I've used `rename` after `str.extract`. You could have told me earlier :-P lol.

Comment: @Corralien sorry I don't remember seeing it earlier in your code, but happy that you know it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression in an dataframe apply

```
txt="200.20356AVAX"
pattern=r"\d+\.*\d*"
print(re.findall(pattern,txt))
```

output:

```
['200.20356']
```