# How to translate numeric code to words using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to make this program that receives a coded string and returns the normal text. For example:

```
input = 42 32 53 53 63 *43 *21 61 *61 21 73 52 
output = hello i am mark
```

I have this dictionary with the equivalences:

```
keypad= {'21': 'a', '22': 'b', '23': 'c', '31': 'd', '32': 'e', '33': 'f', '41': 'g', '42': 'h', '43': 'i',
           '51': 'j', '52': 'k', '53': 'l', '61': 'm', '62': 'n', '63': 'o', '71': 'p', '72': 'q', '74': 'r',
           '74': 's', '81': 't', '82': 'u', '83': 'v', '91': 'w', '93': 'x', '93': 'y', '94': 'z', '*': ' '}
```

I need to use it as it is. I think I need to iterate each number and get the key in the dictionary and add it to an empty string, but I have no idea on how to do it. If anyone has an idea I'd be really thankful.

Comment: What did you try? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
input_value = input('Write something: ').strip().split(' ')


keypad= {'21': 'a', '22': 'b', '23': 'c', '31': 'd', '32': 'e', '33': 'f', '41': 'g', '42': 'h', '43': 'i',
           '51': 'j', '52': 'k', '53': 'l', '61': 'm', '62': 'n', '63': 'o', '71': 'p', '72': 'q', '73': 'r',
           '74': 's', '81': 't', '82': 'u', '83': 'v', '91': 'w', '93': 'x', '93': 'y', '94': 'z', '*': ' '}
output = ""
for a in input_value:
    if '*' not in a:
        output+= keypad[a]
    elif a.startswith('*'):
        output+=' '
        output+=keypad[a[1:]]
    elif a.endswith('*'):
        output+=keypad[a[:-1]]
        output+=' '
print(output)
```

I know the above code gives you an error when the key is not in the dictionary Then You can use this one.

```py
input_value = input('Write something: ').strip().split(' ')


keypad= {'21': 'a', '22': 'b', '23': 'c', '31': 'd', '32': 'e', '33': 'f', '41': 'g', '42': 'h', '43': 'i',
           '51': 'j', '52': 'k', '53': 'l', '61': 'm', '62': 'n', '63': 'o', '71': 'p', '72': 'q', '73': 'r',
           '74': 's', '81': 't', '82': 'u', '83': 'v', '91': 'w', '93': 'x', '93': 'y', '94': 'z', '*': ' '}
output = ""
for a in input_value:
    try:
        if '*' not in a:
            output+= keypad[a]
        elif a.startswith('*'):
            output+=' '
            output+=keypad[a[1:]]
        elif a.endswith('*'):
            output+=keypad[a[:-1]]
            output+=' '
    except KeyError:
        pass
print(output)
```

Comment: If you decided to silence missing keys(which I'm against to), at least don't do that this way. `except KeyError` is enough. Yours is too broad.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I give both solutions one with the error and one that is not. This depends on the user which one he/she is using.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have some missing keys in your dictionary. you need to fix that first then try this:

```py
for item in inp.split():
    if item.startswith("*"):
        print(keypad["*"], end="")
        item = item[1:]
    print(keypad[item], end="")
print()
```

You first check to see it the number starts with a star, if so you need to print the value of `*` separately, then with `item = item[1:]` you change `*N` to `N` and continue. If you don't want to directly print to the stdout, you could have an empty string variable and instead of printing just concatenate the values with that string:

```py
result = ""
for item in inp.split():
    if item.startswith("*"):
        result += keypad["*"]
        item = item[1:]
    result += keypad[item]
print(result)
```

This could also be writen using generator expression if you are interested:

```py
print(
    "".join(
        f"{keypad['*']}{keypad[i[1:]]}" if i.startswith("*") else keypad[i]
        for i in inp.split()
    )
)
```

Comment: This will give an error when the `key` is not in the `dict`.

Comment: @SharimIqbal Then OP should decide what to do, raising exception is helpful in some situations. It indicates that the input is not valid. I don't think it's a good idea to silence all exceptions in every scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

1. [Split on space](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html), loop
2. [Split on digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number), loop
3. [Check if key exist in keypad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary)
4. Append to output

```py
import re

input = '42 32 53 53 63 *43 *21 61 *61 21 73 52'
keypad= {'21': 'a', '22': 'b', '23': 'c', '31': 'd', '32': 'e', '33': 'f', '41': 'g', '42': 'h', '43': 'i', '51': 'j', '52': 'k', '53': 'l', '61': 'm', '62': 'n', '63': 'o', '71': 'p', '72': 'q', '74': 'r', '74': 's', '81': 't', '82': 'u', '83': 'v', '91': 'w', '93': 'x', '93': 'y', '94': 'z', '*': ' '}

result = ''
for i in input.split(' '):
    for j in list(filter(None, re.split('(\d+)', i))):
        if j in keypad:
            result += keypad[j]
        else:
            result += '?'
           
print(input)
print(result)
```

```
42 32 53 53 63 *43 *21 61 *61 21 73 52
hello i am ma?k
```

Since key `73` does not exist in `keypad`, it is decoded as an `?`, you can change the `else` to the desired action when the key does not exist.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHRToMwFIbv@xTnrnRbTNayTZfsFXwB9WJKcWUMaulUND479vxgttjQ5KP/dw4lx/fx0DZmGNzJtyFSsEIE253rSDuSUgjX@DM412Q0rQw/a0OzPG29pPWSZmkn2qRIS3G0vd8XO/qWeim3JPdyQVJrxmegYXxhNBAKIAQLhFAy5hBegRAOQAhOLgRdllzBrVhYwT0C4daMawgnIIQGCKFl3EDwQAhvwJwx/PvaeNqxcIuyCETZGYi@74x3ED6AOP28YA9Esy/GGRPJHyFE2QZy5BrCCG46X7uYpUxtcROOK45r18WsdHW0IbtvG7tIQ/yzs8dirlJfp9RUxsuVY@U4qu31j9E0/PluSh@qp@tc@OCamOFKanoZS9Qw/AI)

Comment: Gonna try that too! Thanks!