# How to split & remove a number in the middle of string in a python?

Tags: python, pandas

**DataFrame**

```
# |Name                |Price    |24h   |Volume(24h)
50|Maker50MKR          |$1,096.96|4,52  |$351,617,227
36|Decentraland36MANA  |$0.9754  |4,11  |$265,949,302
47|Bitcoin SV47BSV     |$60.38   |4,08  |$50,895,114
86|1inch Network861INCH|$0.7637  |3,74  |$72,279,229
38|Hedera38HBAR        |$0.07594 |3,72  |$58,825,304
```

**Desired Result**

```
# |Name         |Ticker|Price    |24h   |Volume(24h)
50|Maker        |MKR   |$1,096.96|4,52  |$351,617,227
36|Decentraland |MANA  |$0.9754  |4,11  |$265,949,302
47|Bitcoin SV   |BSV   |$60.38   |4,08  |$50,895,114
86|1inch Network|1INCH |$0.7637  |3,74  |$72,279,229
38|Hedera       |HBAR  |$0.07594 |3,72  |$58,825,304
```

**The Problem is:**

- there is no fixed number/digit of string (0-100)
- overlap with ticker name (e.g 1inch)
- there is no fixed ticker

Comment: Users on StackOverflow want to help you but not to write code for you. Please provide your approaches so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430079/how-to-split-strings-into-text-and-number

Comment: the *overlap with ticker name (e.g. 1inch)* is going to throw a wrench in your plans. Although it looks like it always has 2 numbers. And actually checking some more, it looks like the number in the string matches the `#` column. If that is the case you can simply do a `string.split()` using the `#` column value to actually split on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creating a simple data frame of your dataset:

```py
simple_dict = {
    "#" : [50, 36, 47, 86, 38],
    "Name" : ["Maker50MKR", "Decentraland36MANA", "Bitcoin SV47BSV", "1inch Network861INCH", "Hedera38HBAR"],
    "Price" : ["$1,096.96", "$0.9754", "$60.38", "$0.7637", "$0.07594"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(simple_dict)
```

```py
>>> df
```

|  | # | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 50 | Maker50MKR | $1,096.96 |
| 1 | 36 | Decentraland36MANA | $0.9754 |
| 2 | 47 | Bitcoin SV47BSV | $60.38 |
| 3 | 86 | 1inch Network861INCH | $0.7637 |
| 4 | 38 | Hedera38HBAR | $0.07594 |

According to this [comment] ([How to split & remove a number in the middle of string in a python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73194511/how-to-split-remove-a-number-in-the-middle-of-string-in-a-python#comment129269866_73194511))

```py
updated_dict = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ans = row["Name"].split(str(row["#"]))
    row.loc["Name"] = ans[0]
    row.loc["Ticker"] = ans[1]
    updated_dict[i] = row

new_df = pd.DataFrame(updated_dict)
```

```py
>>> new_df
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # | 50 | 36 | 47 | 86 | 38 |
| Name | Maker | Decentraland | Bitcoin SV | 1inch Network | Hedera |
| Price | $1,096.96 | $0.9754 | $60.38 | $0.7637 | $0.07594 |
| Ticker | MKR | MANA | BSV | 1INCH | HBAR |

for right show, use `transpose` or `.T`:

```py
>>> new_df.T
```

|  | # | Name | Price | Ticker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 50 | Maker | $1,096.96 | MKR |
| 1 | 36 | Decentraland | $0.9754 | MANA |
| 2 | 47 | Bitcoin SV | $60.38 | BSV |
| 3 | 86 | 1inch Network | $0.7637 | 1INCH |
| 4 | 38 | Hedera | $0.07594 | HBAR |

Comment: Sometimes instead of giving an ans in a single line full of methods, a detailed step by step answer like this really helps

Comment: in my case, I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` because the dataframe have some None value. I just added .dropna() in the `pd.dataframe().dropna()`. It will delete all rows containing None. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: x.Name.split(str(x["#"])), axis=1).values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is that you can split the current name into name and ticker based on the `#` column. The code below is likely not the best code, nor optimal, but it does do what you need...

Perhaps a pandas guru can optimize this. I would be very interested in that at well.

```py
# insert Ticker column
df.insert(df.columns.get_loc("Name")+1, "Ticker", None)


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # split the thing based on '#' column and update the columns
    df.at[index, "Name"], df.at[index, "Ticker"] = row["Name"].split(str(row["#"]))

print(df)
```

resulting df:

```
    #           Name Ticker      Price   24h   Volume(24h)
0  50          Maker    MKR  $1,096.96  4,52  $351,617,227
1  36   Decentraland   MANA    $0.9754  4,11  $265,949,302
2  47     Bitcoin SV    BSV     $60.38  4,08   $50,895,114
3  86  1inch Network  1INCH    $0.7637  3,74   $72,279,229
4  38         Hedera   HBAR   $0.07594  3,72   $58,825,304
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda name: re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z\s]+", name).group())
```